# GKAchievement works with SandBox but doesn´t works with non SandBox

Tags: testing, gamekit

I have a problem with GKAchievement, it works in SandBox mode but doesn´t works in non SandBox mode.
I testet the App on the iOS Simulator and on my iPhone and it works without any errors. Then I uploaded the binary to iTunes Connect and their are no problem during the review. The App is now available on the AppStore and the achievements aren´t working.
My App is already in the AppStore but all of the achievements aren´t working.

Comment: you should provide a stack trace or the errors you're seeing.

Comment: That´s the problem. I testet the App on the iOS Simulator and on my iPhone and it works without any errors. Then I uploaded the binary to iTunes Connect and their are no problem during the review. The App is now available on the AppStore and the achievements aren´t working.